# Get a list of all deleted Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api, delete

When I use this endpoint "GET /interaction/v1/interactions?status=Deleted" of Marketing Cloud API ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionCollection.html)), I am not getting Journeys with status "Deleted"

But when I use SQL query (in the Query Studio for Marketing Cloud), I can get Journeys with status "Deleted"

Is there any way to get a list of deleted Journeys via REST (SOAP) API ?

Comment: what is the use case of getting deleted journeys?